How to keep 1:1 aspect ratio for the child canvas element?
I have prepared a simple test web page at Github (using the main.css file) for my question:

In a vertical flexbox layout I am trying to use ResizeObserver to watch a parent div element with flex-grow:1 and then keep the 1:1 aspect ratio on its child canvas element.
The reason I am trying to the keep the canvas aspect ratio is that in my real app a PixiJS canvas is embedded in a ReactJS app and if I just scale the canvas element to fill the div parent, then the PixiJS content is stretched:

Unfortunately, the parent div element pushes the hint div element off the bottom of the screen -
I think, that something minor is missing in my code, please recommend a fix:


const parentElement = document.getElementById("parent");
const childElement = document.getElementById("child");

const resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver((entries) => {
  for (let entry of entries) {
    const { width, height } = entry.contentRect;
    const minDimension = Math.min(width, height);
    console.log(
      `parent: ${width} x ${height} -> child: ${minDimension} x ${minDimension}`
    );
    childElement.style.width = `${minDimension}px`;
    childElement.style.height = `${minDimension}px`;
  }
});

resizeObserver.observe(parentElement);
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.flexRoot {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: stretch;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

/* the parent holds: status, canvas, hint */
.parent {
  border: 4px solid red;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

canvas {
  width: 1020px;
  height: 1020px;
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 4px green dotted;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.hint,
.status {
  background: lightblue;
  font-style: italic;
  text-align: center;
  flex-grow: 0;
}
<div class="flexRoot">
  <div class="status">Game #1 Score1:Score2</div>
  <div class="parent" id="parent">
    <canvas id="child"></canvas>
  </div>
  <div class="hint">A game hint to do this and that...</div>
</div>




why not use css property 'aspect-ratio: 1;' ?

Yes, I have tried that CSS and the canvas element keeps the same hardcoded size of 1020px x 1020px. Thus a part of the canvas is not shown on smaller browser windows.

To make sure the size of a .parent is determined by a .flexRoot instead of a #child it shouldn't allow an overflow:
.parent {
  overflow: hidden;
}

Optional: a canvas is centered using flex.


const parentElement = document.getElementById("parent");
const childElement = document.getElementById("child");

const resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver((entries) => {
  for (let entry of entries) {
    const {
      width,
      height
    } = entry.contentRect;
    const minDimension = Math.min(width, height);
    console.log(
      `parent: ${width} x ${height} -> child: ${minDimension} x ${minDimension}`
    );
    childElement.style.width = `${minDimension}px`;
    childElement.style.height = `${minDimension}px`;
  }
});

resizeObserver.observe(parentElement);
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.flexRoot {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: stretch;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}


/* the parent holds: status, canvas, hint */

.parent {
  border: 4px solid red;
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

canvas {
  width: 1020px;
  height: 1020px;
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 4px green dotted;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.hint,
.status {
  background: lightblue;
  font-style: italic;
  text-align: center;
  flex-grow: 0;
}
<div class="flexRoot">
  <div class="status">Game #1 Score1:Score2</div>
  <div class="parent" id="parent">
    <canvas id="child"></canvas>
  </div>
  <div class="hint">A game hint to do this and that...</div>
</div>




Thank you, your solution works perfectly, so the overflow: hidden; will stop the parent div from going off the screen? I have just found another solution: setting the position: absolute; for the canvas element instead. Will post it as an answer here too.

Correct, an absolute positioning has a similar effect: #child "escapes" the #parent and can't stretch it anymore.

It does not disrupt the layout anymore!  I like your approach better though, because it has less Javascript code

Would you mind looking at my followup question? I have added a horizontal flex container and now my layout is broken again: https://stackoverflow.com/q/78397794/165071

Looks like it has already been answered.

I have found a solution by setting position: absolute; for the canvas element as shown in my code below:


const parentElement = document.getElementById("parent");
const childElement = document.getElementById("child");

const resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver((entries) => {
  for (let entry of entries) {
    const { width, height } = entry.contentRect;
    const minDimension = Math.min(width, height);
    const maxDimension = Math.max(width, height);

    const diff = Math.floor((maxDimension - minDimension) / 2);
    const paddingLeft = width > height ? diff : 0;
    const paddingTop = width < height ? diff : 0;

    childElement.style.width = `${minDimension}px`;
    childElement.style.height = `${minDimension}px`;
    childElement.style.transform = `translate(${paddingLeft}px, ${paddingTop}px)`;
  }
});
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.flexRoot {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: stretch;
  height: 100vh;
}

/* the parent holds: status, canvas, hint */
.parent {
  border: 4px solid red;
  flex: 1;
}

canvas {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1020px;
  height: 1020px;
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 4px green dotted;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.hint,
.status {
  background: lightblue;
  font-style: italic;
  text-align: center;
}
<div class="flexRoot">
  <div class="status">Game #1 Score1:Score2</div>
  <div class="parent" id="parent">
    <canvas id="child"></canvas>
  </div>
  <div class="hint">A game hint to do this and that...</div>
</div>



The embedded code here at Stackoverflow does not run for some reason, but the updated code at Github works well...
