Why doesn't the flex child shrink in this simple test case webpage?
I had a webpage which was working perfectly and resized the child canvas element (the checkerboard with a bunny), while keeping its 1:1 aspect ratio with a help of ResizeObserver, when the browser window width decreased:

Then I have added a "horizontalFlexContainer" div element around all the elements of that page, so that I could add a grey menu with 4 entries on the left side.
Unfortunately, this has resulted in the issue that the "verticalFlexContainer" refuses to shrink, when the browser width decreases:

Here is my problematic keep-aspect-ratio.html using the main.css
Does anybody please have a recommendation, what is suddenly causing the "resistance" to shrink?


  const parentElement = document.getElementById("parent");
  const childElement = document.getElementById("child");

  const app = new PIXI.Application({
    backgroundColor: 0xccffcc,
    width: 800,
    height: 800,
    view: childElement,
  });

  const resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver((entries) => {
    for (let entry of entries) {
      const { width, height } = entry.contentRect;
      const minDimension = Math.min(width, height);

      // maintain the 1:1 aspect ratio of the child element
      childElement.style.width = `${minDimension}px`;
      childElement.style.height = `${minDimension}px`;
    }
  });

  resizeObserver.observe(parentElement);

  const background = new PIXI.Graphics();
  for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
      if ((i + j) % 2 == 0) {
        background.beginFill(0xccccff);
        background.drawRect(i * 100, j * 100, 100, 100);
        background.endFill();
      }
    }
  }
  app.stage.addChild(background);

  const texture = PIXI.Texture.from("https://pixijs.com/assets/bunny.png");
  const bunny = new PIXI.Sprite(texture);
  bunny.anchor.set(0.5);
  bunny.x = 50;
  bunny.y = 50;
  bunny.width = 100;
  bunny.height = 100;
  app.stage.addChild(bunny);
html,
body,
h3,
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

nav a.active {
  color: red;
}

div.horizontalFlexContainer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: stretch;
}

div.verticalFlexContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: stretch;
  height: 100vh;
}

/* the parent contains: just the canvas element, which observes the parent dimensions */
div.parent {
  border: 4px solid red;
  flex: 1;
  /* center the only child element: the canvas */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  /* prevent the canvas child disrupting the layout */
  overflow: hidden;
}

canvas.child {
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 4px green dotted;
  /* draw the border inside of the canvas element */
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div.hint,
div.status {
  background: lightblue;
  font-style: italic;
  text-align: center;
}
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pixi.js-legacy@7/dist/pixi-legacy.min.js"></script>

<div class="horizontalFlexContainer">
  <div style="background: lightgrey">
    <h3>Select a game!</h3>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>Game 1</li>
        <li>Game 2</li>
        <li>Game 3</li>
        <li>Game 4</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div style="flex-grow: 1">
    <div class="verticalFlexContainer">
      <div class="status">Game #1 Score1:Score2</div>
      <div class="parent" id="parent">
        <canvas class="child" id="child"></canvas>
      </div>
      <div class="hint">A game hint to do this and that...</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




This seems like a use case for CSS's aspect-ratio. Would that work for your situation?

Yes thanks, I have tried it and was unable to make it work, because the canvas element was never scaled down when the browser window was small. Maybe my CSS knowledge is not sufficient to make it work yet.

#child { max-width: 100% }:


const parentElement = document.getElementById("parent");
  const childElement = document.getElementById("child");

  const app = new PIXI.Application({
    backgroundColor: 0xccffcc,
    width: 800,
    height: 800,
    view: childElement,
  });

  const resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver((entries) => {
    for (let entry of entries) {
      const { width, height } = entry.contentRect;
      const minDimension = Math.min(width, height);

      // maintain the 1:1 aspect ratio of the child element
      childElement.style.width = `${minDimension}px`;
      childElement.style.height = `${minDimension}px`;
    }
  });

  resizeObserver.observe(parentElement);

  const background = new PIXI.Graphics();
  for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
      if ((i + j) % 2 == 0) {
        background.beginFill(0xccccff);
        background.drawRect(i * 100, j * 100, 100, 100);
        background.endFill();
      }
    }
  }
  app.stage.addChild(background);

  const texture = PIXI.Texture.from("https://pixijs.com/assets/bunny.png");
  const bunny = new PIXI.Sprite(texture);
  bunny.anchor.set(0.5);
  bunny.x = 50;
  bunny.y = 50;
  bunny.width = 100;
  bunny.height = 100;
  app.stage.addChild(bunny);
html,
body,
h3,
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

nav a.active {
  color: red;
}

div.horizontalFlexContainer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: stretch;
}

div.verticalFlexContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: stretch;
  height: 100vh;
}

/* the parent contains: just the canvas element, which observes the parent dimensions */
div.parent {
  border: 4px solid red;
  flex: 1;
  /* center the only child element: the canvas */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  /* prevent the canvas child disrupting the layout */
  overflow: hidden;
}

canvas.child {
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 4px green dotted;
  /* draw the border inside of the canvas element */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  max-width: 100%;
}

div.hint,
div.status {
  background: lightblue;
  font-style: italic;
  text-align: center;
}
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pixi.js-legacy@7/dist/pixi-legacy.min.js"></script>

<div class="horizontalFlexContainer">
  <div style="background: lightgrey">
    <h3>Select a game!</h3>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>Game 1</li>
        <li>Game 2</li>
        <li>Game 3</li>
        <li>Game 4</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div style="flex-grow: 1">
    <div class="verticalFlexContainer">
      <div class="status">Game #1 Score1:Score2</div>
      <div class="parent" id="parent">
        <canvas class="child" id="child"></canvas>
      </div>
      <div class="hint">A game hint to do this and that...</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



